# How to use transaction scope when inserting multiple rows with generated primary key ids?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I want to insert multiple rows into the `orderdetail` table.
I'm using `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`to make sure all the rows are  able to inserted.

However, when I try to run it I get a primary key violation on `orderdetail`.
I generate the primary key using my custom code.
Also I've implementing read-uncommitted option to read the temporary data.

```
TransactionOptions To = new TransactionOptions(){
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
        };
using (TransactionScope s = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,To))
            foreach (string[] item in allItem)
            {
                //get the item to the entity   
                E_item = new E_item(C_Orderd.getNextOrddId(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")),item[0],item[2],item[3]);
                //insertItem
                C_Orderd.insertItem(E_item);
            }
            s.Complete();
        }
 }
```

(I've enabled msdtc but it just freeze up doing nothing)

Any ideas how to fix this using transaction scope or else
are appreciated.

Comment: well, what is `getNextOrddId(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` ? and is it possible that you're giving multiple rows (in `allItem`) the *same* id? What is the RDBMS underneath all this? Does it not have an auto-incrementing id type?

Comment: By the way, you blame the TransactionScope, but if you (just for test) remove the transaction code did you get the same error? Believe us, it is not a good idea to create your own autoincrement code. Use the database facilities.

Comment: You say you get a primary key violation, but you also say that it just freezes up doing nothing; it can't be both: which is it?

Comment: thanks for the answers.

Comment: thanks for the answers. `getNextOrddId(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` is for get the next primary key.
im using mysql
im not using autoincrement id because i think the id is could be longger than max Int digit. `string[] item` is the attribute for the item. allI tem is `List<string[]>` and it contain all the item that i want to be enter

get primary key violation when im not specify the isolation level,
then frezees up when i use the isolation level.

without transaction scope the code are running smoothly.

Comment: yaa thats the problem. every multiple rows in all item get the same id.
so example: last id in database. 201606140001. then if i got 2 item in `allItem` the error is Primary key violation 201606140002. the system get the first auto id correct but the second is not.

Comment: i'm so so so sorry this is my fault. actually my querry to get max ID was wrong.
sorry for take your precious time.